# Check availability of folder/files

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CWSSCheck()

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Position_by_Fixture" Then

Call FileCheck

ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Group_PositionList" Then
MsgBox "This is the Group Position List. Convert the Shelfstock to the old 
format using the 'Convert Shelfstock' function and try again.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Format"

Else
MsgBox "This workbook doesn't have a Shelfstock sheet. Please open a valid Shelfstock file and try again.", vbExclamation, "Shelfstock Not Found"

End If
End Sub

Sub FileCheck()

'Check the REQUIRED FILES folder
UserForm1.Show

Dim RFPath As String
Dim UOLPath As String
Dim SOLPath As String

RFPath = ""
On Error Resume Next
RFPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\REQUIRED FILES\"
On Error GoTo 0

UOLPath = ""
On Error Resume Next
UOLPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\REQUIRED FILES\UPDATED_OUTLET_LIST.xlsx"
On Error GoTo 0

SOLPath = ""
On Error Resume Next
SOLPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\REQUIRED FILES\SAP_OUTLET_LIST.xlsx"
On Error GoTo 0

If RFPath = "" Then
    UserForm1.CheckBox3.Value = False
Else
    UserForm1.CheckBox3.Value = True
End If

If SOLPath = "" Then
    UserForm1.CheckBox2.Value = False
Else
    UserForm1.CheckBox2.Value = True
End If

If UOLPath = "" Then
    UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = False
Else
    UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = True
End 

End Sub
```

I wrote the following code to check for a folder in the user's desktop and two files inside that folder and then update three checkboxes in a userform.

But every time i run this i get different results regardless the availability of the files in the said folder. The code seems to be checking the checkboxes at random.

I'm having a hard time seeing what's wrong with the code. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Not for points but I guess you chose FSO over DIR? Or maybe you actually did not understand my answer? Feel free to select Jeremy's answer but in preference to FSO (FileSystemObject) I recommend using the (VBA methods) Dir, FileCopy and Kill. Use FSO only where necessary.

Comment: Hey sorry I appreciate your answer but Jimmy's answer provided me an immediate solution which i needed whereas with yours i had to experiment with the code a little. Could you share the advantages of using VBA methods as you mentioned over FSO in this instance? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise using the `file scripting object` to avoid the volatility where you can come up against issues if looping the function:

```
Sub FileCheck()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim CheckForFolder As Boolean, CheckForFile1 As Boolean, CheckForFile2 As Boolean

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
CheckForFolder = False
CheckForFile1 = False
CheckForFile2 = False

'Check the REQUIRED FILES folder
UserForm1.Show

If FSO.FolderExists(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\REQUIRED FILES\") Then CheckForFolder = True ' Checks for the folder. If it exsists, set boolean to "True"

If FSO.FileExists(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\REQUIRED FILES\UPDATED_OUTLET_LIST.xlsx") Then CheckForFile1 = True ' Checks for the 1st file. If it exsists, set boolean to "True"

If FSO.FileExists(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\REQUIRED FILES\SAP_OUTLET_LIST.xlsx") Then CheckForFile2 = True ' Checks for the 2nd file. If it exsists, set boolean to "True"


If CheckForFolder = False Then ' Checks the boolean, asings the checkbox accordingly
    UserForm1.CheckBox3.Value = False
Else
    UserForm1.CheckBox3.Value = True
End If

If CheckForFile2 = False Then ' Checks the boolean, asings the checkbox accordingly
    UserForm1.CheckBox2.Value = False
Else
    UserForm1.CheckBox2.Value = True
End If

If CheckForFile1 = False Then ' Checks the boolean, asings the checkbox accordingly
    UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = False
Else
    UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = True
End

Set FSO = Nothing 'Tidy up the memory

End Sub
```

Comment: @NickRazzleflamm No problem :)

Answer (score 2):

```
RFPath = ""
On Error Resume Next
RFPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\REQUIRED FILES\"
On Error GoTo 0
```

You are creating the path in a String Variable but not checking if it exists or not. Use this function

```
Public Function FileFolderExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo EarlyExit
    If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
EarlyExit:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Ex:

```
Debug.Print FileFolderExists(RFPath)
```

Also to store in a String variable you do not need the `On Error Resume Next`. You can directly do

```
RFPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\REQUIRED FILES\"
```